# when i run the code,i didnot see my image,just appears white screen on device,why?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Image.asset('images/dice1.png'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `pubspec.yaml` add the `assets`:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - images/dice1.png
```

Make sure the directory is correct, more info here:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

Answer (score 0):

You have to return runapp or you can use an arrow instead.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

Comment: can anyone please tell me that where to use child where not.i mean we have use image in child,but we haven't make child to expanded.totally confused.

Comment: We use child in widgets. Some of them have children. If you press alt and click on the name of widget in your code, the list of  properties will be shown.